# Selenium find button

Tags: javascript, button, xpath, selenium

Hy. I have a problem with selenium IDE. I have a button in a table that I must click on.

```
Command: click
Target: xpath=//table[@id='mainForm:dataTable']//tr[contains(., 'test1')]/td[9]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(., 'Edit')]/a
```

When I click the button 'Find' of selenium it show's me the button 'Edit' for the person 'test1' in my table. So selenium finds the button, that means what I write in target must be correctly.

The problem is, if I wanna run the test, selenium says :

```
[error] Element //table[@id='mainForm:dataTable']//tr[contains(., 'test1')]/td[9]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(., 'Löschen')]/a not found
```

and I don#t know why.

Please help me with this problem :)

Comment: You do realize that the two XPaths are different from each other?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe row where this text has to be present is another than 9 ? maybe try`/td[contains(., 'Löschen')]/a` if you don't have another td like this on page. Good practice will be sign in some way that element in your server script (for example add rel= or title= or just specific id=) and find that by this parameter.

Try to run test growing this xpath from none, thet you should catch a situation where exactly requested element not exists, like:

```
//table
//table[@id='mainForm:dataTable']
//table[@id='mainForm:dataTable']//tr
//table[@id='mainForm:dataTable']//tr[contains(., 'test1')]
//table[@id='mainForm:dataTable']//tr[contains(., 'test1')]/td
//table[@id='mainForm:dataTable']//tr[contains(., 'test1')]/td[9]
```

And so on, until error will appear

Maybe you have some javascripts on page that do modifications in DOM tree

Comment: thx for the quick answer. I'll try it. The problem is the buttons have the same id =). so I must find it in an other way. Selenium finds the button with xpath=//table[@id='mainForm:dataTable']//tr[contains(., 'test1')]/td[9]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(., 'Edit')]/a but don't wanna click on it.